# ZK rollups: How is state diff data in batches checked for correctness?

Tags: rollups, zkevm

Situation: ZK rollups don’t need to publish any transaction data on L1 to ensure correct state transition because the zk proof takes care of correct state transition without knowing (i.e. zk) anything about transactions. Nevertheless zk rollups publish state diff data on L1 for each transaction in order for users to be able reconstruct the complete rollup state in case the rollup operator stops his work (here details for starknet: https://docs.starknet.io/documentation/architecture_and_concepts/Network_Architecture/on-chain-data/).

Question: How is it ensured that this additional state diff data is in line with the overall state transition which is controlled via the zk proof? The zk proof only checks the state transition but not the additionally provided state diff data which is only needed to reconstruct the full rollup state but which is not needed for correct state transition, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State diffs are inputs to the verifier smart contract which checks whether they correspond to the output produced by the state transition function.

Comment: Thx a lot, donnoh